# Why MailController doesn't show To and Body text?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this code on Objective-C:

```
- (IBAction)Mail:(id)sender {
    NSString *MailTitle = @"Mi Opinion About this App";
    NSString *MailBody = @"Hi, I am an user of this app and I think that ";
    NSArray *MailTo = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"contact@domain.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *MailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    MailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [MailController setSubject:MailTitle];
    [MailController setMessageBody:MailBody isHTML:NO];
    [MailController setToRecipients:MailTo];
    [self presentViewController:MailController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

It shows properly the subject, but the fields "To", and "Body" are empty in iOS simulator!

Comment: what's the code in `setToRecipients` ?

Comment: It access to MailTo, the name of the NSArray with the recipients

Comment: irrelevant to your problem; starting the names of methods and variables with a capital letter is very bad practice.

Comment: @Mario post more code in `MailController` so we can help you.